# The most frequent substring of length X

Tags: algorithm, substring

We have a string of length N and the number X.

How to find the most frequent substring of length X in the string of length N in average O(N) time?

I think, here is a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597025?tab=votes#tab-top

I would like to ask you how to prove that the number of used hashing functions is only a constant.

Comment: The linked question is marked `homework` - I can only assume this is too.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Most common substring of length X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597025/most-common-substring-of-length-x)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [suffix tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree) should give this in O(n) time worst case, with O(n) space usage.

In particular check the [Functionality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree#Functionality) section of the above wiki page under the Properties of Strings sub section, which mentions

> Find the most frequently occurring substrings of a minimum length in Θ(n) time.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this kind of hash function. Lets condider that each string is number in 256 base notation (instead of our 10 based). So for each X length substring we can get its value in 10 base notation this way:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>


int main()
{
    std::string s;
    int x;
    std::cin >> s >> x;

    unsigned const int base = 256;
    unsigned long long xPowOfBase = 1;
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 1; i <= x; ++i)
        xPowOfBase *= base;

    unsigned long long firstXLengthSubString = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < x; ++i)
    {
        firstXLengthSubString *= base;
        firstXLengthSubString += s[i];
    }

    unsigned long long nextXLengthSubstring = firstXLengthSubString;

    std::map<unsigned long long, std::pair<int, int> > hashTable;
    for(;i <= s.size(); ++i)
    {
        if(hashTable.find(nextXLengthSubstring) != hashTable.end())
            ++hashTable[nextXLengthSubstring].first;
        else
            hashTable.insert(std::make_pair(nextXLengthSubstring, std::make_pair(1, i - x)));

        if(i != s.size())
        {
            nextXLengthSubstring *= base;
            nextXLengthSubstring += s[i];
            nextXLengthSubstring -= s[i - x] * xPowOfBase;
        }
    }

    std::map<unsigned long long, std::pair<int, int> >::iterator it = hashTable.begin();
    std::map<unsigned long long, std::pair<int, int> >::iterator end_it = hashTable.end();
    std::pair<int, int> maxCountAndFirstPosition = std::make_pair(0, -1);

    for(;it != end_it; ++it)
    {
        if(maxCountAndFirstPosition.first < it->second.first)
            maxCountAndFirstPosition = it->second;
    }

    std::cout << maxCountAndFirstPosition.first << std::endl;
    std::cout << s.substr(maxCountAndFirstPosition.second, x) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This will work on `O(n * log(n))` , to make it `O(n)` just change std::map wiht any hash table.