# How to find top 10 frequent substring from string databases

Tags: string, frequency-analysis, longest-substring

Assume I have a txt file, each line represents a string. Is there some efficient way to find out top 10 frequent substrings.

The difficulty is that there are too large size of substring permutation for a given string. Given a `N` length of string, it has total `C(N,0)+C(N,1)+..C(N,N)` kinds of substring.

================================================
[**Update**]

The question is similar with "[a link][Algorithm to find the most common substrings in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14670632/algorithm-to-find-the-most-common-substrings-in-a-string)" , but both are **NOT** the SAME. The difference is that I tried to find out top 10 frequent substring among all **strings** while it is only to find longest substring in one string in "[a link] [Algorithm to find the most common substrings in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14670632/algorithm-to-find-the-most-common-substrings-in-a-string) to find the most common substrings in **one string**" which is only local optimization.

Though one substring is infrequent in all strings via method in "[a link] [Algorithm to find the most common substrings in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14670632/algorithm-to-find-the-most-common-substrings-in-a-string)", it is possible to be most frequent. For example, I have 10 strings, 
string              most frequent
str1                  sub_str1  --4 times
str2                  sub_str2  -- 4 times
..
str10                 sub_str10

The most frequent substring of each string are different and each occurs 4 times. There is possibility that another substring named sub_minor that exists occurs in all string and happens only 1 times. As a result, this sub_minor string is most frequent since it occurs 10 which exceeds all other sub_str string.

All sub_str all only local optimization instead of global optimization and my problem is mainly for global optimization, which is different from "[a link] [Algorithm to find the most common substrings in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14670632/algorithm-to-find-the-most-common-substrings-in-a-string)"

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: either of C++ and java