# Finding most sequences of specified length

Tags: python, search, sequence

I'm trying to write python code that will take a string and a length, and search through the string to tell me which sub-string of that particular length occurs the most, prioritizing the first if there's a tie.

For example, `"cadabra abra" 2` should return `ab`

I tried:

```
import sys

def main():
    inputstring = str(sys.argv[1])
    length = int(sys.argv[2])
    Analyze(inputstring, length)    


def Analyze(inputstring, length):
    count = 0;
    runningcount = -1;
    sequence = ""
    substring = ""
    for i in range(0, len(inputstring)):    
        substring = inputstring[i:i+length]
        for j in range(i+length,len(inputstring)):
            #print(runningcount)
            if inputstring[j:j+2] == substring:
                print("runcount++")
                runningcount += 1
                print(runningcount)         
                if runningcount > count:
                    count = runningcount
                    sequence = substring


    print(sequence)             


main()
```

But can't seem to get it to work. I know I'm at least doing something wrong with the counts, but I'm not sure what. This is my first program in Python too, but I think my problem is probably more with the algorithm than the syntax.

Comment: why `if inputstring[j:j+2] == substring:` ? shouldn't be `if inputstring[j:j+length] == substring:` instead?

Comment: Check out this answer to a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14670769/1795128 . Using the Counter class simplifies the problem a lot

Comment: Yea it would be j+length, thanks. I'll try taking a look at counter class, but I was trying to do this without researching too much python specific stuff yet

Comment: Do you count overlapping strings? E.g., should `'aaabbcbb' 2` return `'aa'` (occurring twice counting the overlap, and beating `'bb'` by occurring earlier), or should it return `'bb'`? Since you accepted Iron Fist's answer below, it looks like you do want to count the overlap, but that's not clear from the problem description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use built-in method, they will make your life easier, this way:

```
>>> s = "cadabra abra"
>>> x = 2
>>> l = [s[i:i+x] for i in range(len(s)-x+1)]
>>> l
['ca', 'ad', 'da', 'ab', 'br', 'ra', 'a ', ' a', 'ab', 'br', 'ra']
>>> max(l, key=lambda m:s.count(m))
'ab'
```

**EDIT:**

Much simpler syntax as per [Stefan Pochmann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1672429/stefan-pochmann) comment:

```
>>> max(l, key=s.count)
```

Comment: `max(l, key=s.count)`

Comment: Wow this way was much more simple

Comment: Third line should be: `l = [s[i:i+x] for i in range(len(s) - x + 1)]` to adjust the range when `x` changes.

Comment: You cannot omit the `key=` in `key=s.count`; it's a keyword-only argument.

Answer (score 1):

```
import sys
from collections import OrderedDict

def main():
    inputstring = sys.argv[1]
    length = int(sys.argv[2])
    analyze(inputstring, length)

def analyze(inputstring, length):
    d = OrderedDict()
    for i in range(0, len(inputstring) - length + 1):    
        substring = inputstring[i:i+length]
        if substring in d:
            d[substring] += 1
        else:
            d[substring] = 1
    maxlength = max(d.values())
    for k,v in d.items():
        if v == maxlength:
            print(k)
            break

main()
```

Comment: for my sample input this returns the length not the sequence. also I think the print is missing a )

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but this isn't returning anything for me when I use my sample input

Comment: I used it with your sample input at the top and it works for me.  What input are you using?

Comment: Hmm I'm using CodeRunner with my arguments set to: `"cadabra abra" 2`

Comment: Ok it's working, don't know what I did wrong the first time. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Pretty good stab at a solution for a first Python program.  As you learn the language, spend some time reading the excellent documentation.  It is full of examples and tips.

For example, the standard library includes a `Counter` class for counting things (obviously) and an `OrderedDict` class which remebers the ording in which keys are entered.  But the documentation includes an example that combines the two to make an `OrderedCounter`, which can be used to solve you problem like this:

```
from collections import Counter, OrderedDict

class OrderedCounter(Counter, OrderedDict):
    pass

def analyze(s, n):
    substrings = (s[i:i+n] for i in range(len(s)-n+1))
    counts = OrderedCounter(substrings)
    return max(counts.keys(), key=counts.__getitem__)

analyze("cadabra abra", 2)
```