# Most common phrase

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

The Google Play app store recently rolled out a new feature for the Android app, which groups common phrases that reviewers left. I was thinking about which algorithm might accomplish this with as little space and time as possible, but haven't yet come up with a satisfying answer.

The feature looks something like this:

> This app has 10.000.000 reviews
>
> "**Addictive**" : 1234 reviews
>
> - "This is **addictive**!"
> - "Can't put this **addictive** app down."
> - ...
>
> "**Bad framerate**": 12345 reviews
>
> - "This app has a **bad framerate** on my device"
> - "The main menu has a **bad framerate**"
> - ...

The top 5 phrases are displayed (k=5). A phrase can have 5 words max (l_max=5). A popular app can have 10 million comments with 100 words each (n=10E9 words).

### Trivial approaches

#### Hashmap

A simple algorithm for l_max=1 would be:

1. Drop all words into a hashmap, counting their frequency *(O(n) time, O(n) space)*
2. Select k top phrases *O(nlogk) via heap, O(k) space*

If l_max > 1, step 1 would create a hashmap that needs *O(n/*l_max) space*, which is too much.

#### Nussinov

The Nussinov algorithm (see [Algorithm to find the most common substrings in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14670632/algorithm-to-find-the-most-common-substrings-in-a-string)) would be a great match, but it needs *O(n**2)* space, so we probably shouldn't use that one here.