# Counting occurences of string without knowing the string

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of approximately 20000 strings and I want to count how often each string occurs in the list, however I don't know all the different unique strings in the list. I have tried experimenting with the `list.count('string')` but without knowing all the unique strings. Is there anyway of reading the list and getting an output of all the unique strings present. Thanks for any help

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49316102/count-the-number-occurrences-of-each-word-in-a-text-python

Answer (score 1):

I think this will solve your problem.

```
from collections import Counter

words = ["hello", "world", "hello", "world"]

print(Counter(words)) #Counter({'hello': 2, 'world': 2})
```

For Reference check [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

Comment: Thank you this has given me the desired results